# regex match if line matches or starts and ends with angle brackets

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm processing a file line by line with ruby(pcre regex) and the idea is to count how many lines are used excluding page markers, empty lines and markup tags

```
 1. [==| Page 4 |==]
 2.
 3. 上側
 4.
 5. 勉州爛 夜 菌
 6.
 7. 洲⑪蝿 香n
 8.
 9. 本聘
10.
11. [==| Page 5 |==]
12.
13. <IMAGE
14. <IMAGE>
15. IMAGE>
16.
17. [==| Page 6 |==]
18.
19. 欝輛蓼 \縄《卿⑪儡
```

I know how to use ignore headings and and empty lines with this regex `/^(?!\[==\| Page \d+ \|==\]).+$/`

but I'm not quite sure how to also ignore tags. the regex to match these tags that I'm using are as simple as `/^<.*>$/`, and I'm not sure how to invert it.

the result after scanning should be `["上側", "勉州爛 夜 菌", "洲⑪蝿 香n", "本聘", "<IMAGE", "IMAGE>", "欝輛蓼 \縄《卿⑪儡"].length #=> 7`

Comment: Ruby regex engine is Onigmo, not PCRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use or in look ahead expression to exclude other lines too!

`^(?!\[==\| Page \d+ \|==\]|$|<.*>).*$`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gbFBLq/1/)

Answer (score 1):

### Chaining Inverted Matches

You have a number of ways to invert matches in Ruby, including [Enumerable#grep_v](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) and [Enumerable#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject). While you could certainly do it as a complex regular expression, that makes your code much less testable and harder to read. Instead, leverage some of the core methods to build up your logic and/or regex patterns, rather than using one complex regular expression.

For example, assuming you've slurped your file into a *file* variable:

```
page_marker = /\[==\| Page \d+ \|==\]/
tag_markers = /^<.*?>$/

file.lines.map(&:chomp).
  grep_v(page_marker).
  grep_v(tag_markers).
  reject { |line| line.empty? }.
  count

#=> 7
```

Granted that there are many other ways to express this, the chained method approach has the key benefits of:

1. Being fairly readable.
2. Clearly communicating the step-wise intent of the code.
3. Being composable, and therefore easy to modify or extend.
4. Allowing you to see the results of each step in the method chain in irb if you need to debug it.

Other answers may steer you towards [negative or positive lookahead/lookbehind assertions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors), but for maintainability and testability I'd strongly encourage a more composeable approach.

Comment: grep_v does seem excellent for inverting regexs, correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't grep_v end up adding the all the lines of my file to ram since we're manipulating an array?

Comment: @JaackoTorus This solution optimizes for readability and testability. How big is your real file, and do you experience heavy swapping when processing it? Slurping files always has memory usage as a downside, so you’d need a very different solution if memory is your primary constraint. Unless your file is GB in size, it’s probably a needless concern so long as your arrays eventually go out of scope and get garbage collected.

Comment: no it's not nearly as bad, I just wanted to get used to the pattern since I'm starting out and assumed that loading files to ram seemed to always be a worse idea. Thank you for feedback